# What IP Blocks does ChinaNet.com own?

Tags: ip

We are getting many fake account and spam attempts from IP addresses originating from ChinaNet.com. How can I discover all of their IP blocks? I viewed a report from 2001 that mentioned they did not protect against abuse.

http://www.dolphinwave.org/spam/CHINANET-GD.txt

Comment: Everything you need to know is in this file: `ftp://ftp.apnic.net/apnic/stats/apnic/delegated-apnic-extended-latest` Find all `ipv4` ranges where the country is `CN`. Each one gives you the base addresses plus number of addresses. I use a script to turn this into `iptables` rules. The script has a list of whitelisted countries; all else is blocked from contacting port 25.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, any report from 2001 is worth slightly less than the paper on which it is printed.  It's 10 year old data.

Second, You are reaching for the wrong solution: You should implement real heuristic-based spam filtering, not just block IP ranges because you feel like it.

Third, If you ***really*** want to do do this then AS numbers are your fiends.
Chinanet is AS23650.  [This page](http://bgp.he.net/AS23650#_asinfo) has all sorts of interesting BGP info, including all of their IPv4 and IPv6 prefixes (as seen by Hurricane Electric's infrastructure).

Answer (score 0):

There are many services out there than can provide this information.  The one I would recommend is from MaxMind.

http://www.maxmind.com/app/isp